# How to completely delete programs that came with my computer?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I know this must have been asked already, so you can redirect me to the posts.

I bought my acer laptop a few months ago and with it came an antivirus program. I think it was Avast. I immediately uninstalled it but then, a few weeks ago, I reset my laptop (windows) and I noticed it came back. I had to go through the process of uninstalling all the unwanted apps again.

Knowing myself, I know that in a few more months I will want to reset my pc again. That means I will have to uninstall all the programs again afterwards. I know I can do a full format but I don't really want to do that.

Is there any other way. Keep in mind that I already uninstalled the programs.

Comment: Your system restore image that is stored on a hidden partition of the hard drive, and is used to restore or repair your PC, will always contain all these pieces of software as they are part of the manufacturers install image. When you "reset" your PC, you are restoring the system portion from that image. You could attempt to edit that directly, but it would likely cause issues later. Why do you need to reset your PC so often may be the better question, it shouldn't be necessary at all.

Comment: I don't actually need to reset my pc that often. When it comes to my computer, I am a clean freak. That's why I reset it so often. There was a time when I'd format my computer every month, after backing up my important files. But it soon got old because each time it had to update the software.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following procedure to permanently rid your machine of the OEM trial applications:

1. First and foremost, make a backup copy of your `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore` folder on an external USB drive or optical disc.  It can save you a great deal of time if you have any missing device drivers after the reload.
2. Click on the `Start` button.
3. Select `Settings`
4. Select the `Update & security` category
5. Select the `Recovery` option on the left

[image: Update & security]

6. Under `More recovery options` select the link that says `Learn how to start fresh with a clean installation of Windows`.

[image: More recovery options]

7. This will take you to Microsoft's web page titled `Start fresh with a clean installation of Windows 10`.

[image: Download tool now]

8. Take the time to read through the instructions and then select `Download tool now`.
9. Execute the `RefreshWindowsTool.exe` file that you downloaded.
10. When you arrive at the screen that says `Give Your PC a Fresh Start`, select `Keep personal files only` and click `Start` on the bottom-right.

[image: Give your PC a fresh start]

11. After the procedure is done, the OS install and Windows Updates will hopefully install all of the appropriate device drivers.  Open the `devmgmt.msc` interface with administrator privileges to double-check.

[image: Missing Drivers]

12. If there are missing drivers, temporarily attach the USB drive or optical disc that contains the `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore` we referenced in step #1.
13. Right-click each unknown device, select `Update driver software`, and browse to the external drive that holds the DriverStore backup folder.
14. Initiate a final reboot when you are done.  Your Windows 10 machine should now have a clean install without the OEM trial applications, and the next time you simply want to execute a `Reset` it will restore back to this state.

(Source:  [How to Easily Reinstall Windows 10 Without the Bloatware](http://www.howtogeek.com/265054/how-to-easily-reinstall-windows-10-without-the-bloatware/))