# Installing the WiFi driver

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

I have bought a Medion Erazer X6821 notebook which supposedly comes with an Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230 card. The Windows license shipping with it is Windows 7, so I just stuck with that. I did, however, install Windows 7 Professional from scratch since I do not know what the previous owner did.

From the Medion website I downloaded all the driver installation packages. The wireless driver is some 300 MB installer that also installs some (apparently useless) extra software to manage wireless networks. After installing the driver and all the additional software, the furthest I get is this:

> [image]
>
> **Adapter Problem**
>
> Driver is not installed

Apparently that special Intel software cannot get the hardware to work but just tell me that the driver is missing. Uninstalling everything, restarting, installing again does not help.

In the device manager, I see one device which seems to be lacking a driver:

> [image]
>
> - Other devices
>
>   - Network controller
> - Audio, video and game controller

I tried to right-click on that device and manually install the driver. It cannot find anything from Windows Update. Pointing it to the directory of that driver installer did not bring up anything either. Windows just cannot find a driver for this hardware.

The ethernet controller was also cumbersome to install, however that works now. It is shown correctly in the device manager:

> [image]
>
> - Network adapters
>
>   - Killer e2200 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.20)
> - Processors

When I open that Intel utility, it also just says that the driver is not installed:

> [image]
>
> Driver is not installed
>
> Troubleshooting ...

In the list of network adapters, only the ethernet one is shown, the wireless one is not listed:

> [image]
>
> LAN connection
> Network 2
> Killer e2200 PCI-E Gigabit Etherne...

I am rather lost now. Installing the Windows 7 driver from the manufacturer on Windows 7 is supposed to work. Is there something that I can do to get the wireless network on that laptop working?

Comment: For future reference, whenever you are going to perform a clean install on a Windows 7, 8.1, or 10 machine and you aren't quite sure if you already have a copy of all the device drivers, manually backup the `%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\DriverStore` folder first.  I explain why within a previous answer:  [How to completely delete programs that came with my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1150268/how-to-completely-delete-programs-that-came-with-my-computer/1150278#1150278)

Comment: Good idea! I had found the [Medion support page](http://www.medion.com/gb/service/start/_product.php?msn=30013952&gid=1) and assumed that download all the drivers from there would be possible. I find it very strange that one cannot bootstrap a Windows installation with the drivers from the manufacturer :-/.

Comment: install the latest Intel WIFI driver directly from Intel and not from Medeon: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26527/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-and-Drivers-for-IT-Admins?v=t

Comment: Huh, that directly worked. I wonder why the Medion installer doesn't do what it is supposed to do. So this is done, thank you!

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer so that you can accept it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using drivers from OEMs like Medion, [download and install the driver directly from Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26527/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-and-Drivers-for-IT-Admins?v=t).

OEMs often provide extremely old drivers.