# How to block Windows 10 1607 update completely

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I'm running 1511 version of Windows 10 Pro. Update 1607 doesn't work at all. It was tried to be installed about 10 times and each time it fails completely. I have set postpone updates to avoid installing this update over and over but now it doesn't work any more for this update.

So now it's being downloaded over and over, after restart it fails installing and then it will be downloaded again and fails again. Is there any way to block this update?

I'm afraid it will either destroy my SSD one day or after 100 or so attempt finally it will crash Windows and I will have to install it from scratch.

Comment: **You can't;**  You can only defer feature updates for 6 months.  It's been 6 months since 1607 was released.  So the solution is to use the 1607 ISO to install the upgrade.  If you want the rights to use the 1511 LTSB use "Windows 10 Enterprise 1511 LTSB"

Comment: @Ramhound You mean installing Windows from scratch? I was trying also media creation tool or standalone updates but one of them also failed and the other said it was not for my Windows

Comment: No;  I don't mean installing Windows from scratch.  I mean download the 1607 ISO directly from Microsoft, DO NOT USE the Media Creation Tool to do that, mount the ISO and install the update.

Comment: Something to help point you in the right direction:  http://superuser.com/a/1143353/650163

Comment: @Run5k I've tried already everything (also install from ISO with containing apps and user data). All updates fails so it it seams maybe the only way is clean install but it's really unbelievable that after a few failures for same update Windows will try to install it over and over.

Comment: I'm sorry to heat that.  It sounds like something unusual happened with your system's configuration that made the update problematic.  I know that performing a clean install is rather time consuming, but will obviously alleviate the problem.  Before you do that, ensure that you create a backup copy of your `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore` folder to an external USB drive or DVD disc first.  That will help ensure that you can easily restore all of your device drivers afterwards, similar to this scenario:  http://superuser.com/a/1150278/650163

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek - I have finally upgraded 1511 to 1607, keeping files and programs, after months of what you report: hours of down-load and install, freeze at 87%, then restore 1511. I finally grasped the nettle and used the ISO, but it wouldn't upgrade, telling me to return to the normal boot! However, on rebooting I tried running `setup.exe` from the USB root directory and it eventually got through 87% to complete the upgrade. If it's relevant, I chose _not_ to install updates while installing. [W10 installations have been dreadful on W7/non-EFI upgrades, but W8.1/EFI systems have been OK.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up, It seems there's no way to block this update any more. The only way to install it in my case was downloading ISO file download [media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) and choosing to create ISO file, burning it to DVD and when running choosing installation of fresh system. All other methods in my case failed.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody linked this question to mine as it was similar so I figured that after finding the solution I should also post it here so more people could find it:

> EDIT, SOLUTION FOUND!!!
>
> Okay so it looks like I may have cracked this :D
>
> 1. Install Windows 10 1511 with NIC cable unplugged.
> 2. Connect the NIC cable and download Microsoft's Wushowhide tool (KB 3073930).
> 3. Let Windows Update find updates.
> 4. Use the Wushowhide tool to block the 1607 update.
> 5. As it's already downloaded or downloading the 1607 update you need to stop the Windows Update service, delete everything in the download
>      cache, then restart the service and reboot.
> 6. That's it, it should now download and apply all updates except 1607 (and updates for 1607).
>
> Glad I was able to solve this instead of having to drop £1K on a new
>   CPU/board/RAM, but I still say it was a TERRIBLE move by Microsoft to
>   make an update that was causing widespread issues mandatory.

Comment: This worked for me, although you'd be running against time since 1607 process might start earlier

Comment: Just preventively stop the `wuauserv` service before restoring the network connection, and you should have plenty of seconds for *wushowhide* to run first.

Answer (score 0):

try using **WinaeroTweaker**, and set the settings notify to update. It worked when I used windows 10.

download link - http://winaero.com/request.php?1796

Comment: I can't understand how Winaero Tweaker is going to help ?

Comment: as windows starts updating automatically from your build 1507, it will prevent it from happening, and you will be able to enjoy your same build.

Comment: or if you do wanna install 1607 update you can download it manually from - [link](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb3176929)

Answer (score 0):

I eliminated updating Win 10 this way:

1. I determined what IP this update was originating from and blocked it with a firewall rule.
2. I blocked the win10 Update exe in my firewall's Programs db.
3. I took ownership of the update file and folders (one in c drive, one in Windows) and denied access to System and Trusted Installer. Then I deleted them.
4. Finally, I wrote a firewall rule to block the Microsoft update service IP. Now I pick and choose what updates I want to download and install manually.
   And the aggravating update pop-up and the automatic download of Win 10 Anniversary Edition is GONE!
5. As an added precaution I blocked my anti-virus program from updating  to a newer version,in case MS forces the company to change engine to keep me from blocking them.